# How common is it for boys to masturbate in early childhood (before kindergarten)?

Tags: pediatrics, sexuality, children-kids, developmental-milestones

How common is it for male children to masturbate in early childhood (before kindergarten)?

Is it normal for extremely young male boys to fondle their own genitals?
Is that part of normal human biology or not?

Comment: To possibly survive here, it is imperative to remove all personal aspects of the question. No one can offer an opinion on your personal circumstances here. Additionally, we expect evidence of prior research. What have your other attempts to find an answer given you? The Quora story you told is not helpful as prior research because you don't have it in hand.

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree that nobody can offer an opinion on my personal circumstances. In other words, nobody can say whether my father was abusive or not. However, a medical expert in human sexual development, (or maybe an expert in childhood development) should be able to say whether children younger than 5 years of age masterbate or not.

Comment: @BryanKrause I only mentioned personal aspects about my life in order to explain the motivation behind such a strange question.

Comment: Yes, so keep it to the question that can be answered and leave the personal stuff out. The context you provide makes it a far more problematic question; the simple question itself is not very strange, parents and pediatricians are certainly interested in such information. I'm certain similar questions have been asked on the Parenting SE.

Comment: I’m not expert in this field but parenting does have similar questions https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/sex-play-in-young-children?r=SearchResults

Comment: @AwkwardMedicalQuestions First, this isn't an uncomfortable question here that you need to apologize for. It's a perfectly valid question (following Bryan's edits) and I assure you that equally and even more sensitive issues have been posted here before. But I don't think this is the best site for it. I think Parenting.SE would probably be the best place to start, and Psychology.SE would be my next choice. So if you don't have any objections, I will migrate it for you.

Comment: @CareyGregory the question is essentially "Do children masturbate?" which isn't really related to parenting. Not sure about Psychology.SE as well, never really visited it. So you decided to leave the question here?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating The OP hasn't returned since asking the question and therefore never responded to my comment, and now it has a highly upvoted answer.

Comment: The edit you made was unnecessary and inappropriate. Your motivations for asking aren't really important, and adding personal details just turns this back into a personal advice question. Also, substantially changing a question two years later when it has a highly upvoted answer isn't quite fair to the answerer. Therefore, I've reverted your edits. If you want to know if the behavior is indicative of possible molestation, then Parenting or Psychology & Neuroscience would be the places to ask. The question is too old to for me to migrate it for you.

Comment: Hi Carey - they have asked basically the same question over on Parenting, but in a way that leads me to believe it is not asked in good faith, and that they didn't read Fizz's excellent answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to one [2010 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2994165/), which actually tried to identify the correlates of the behavior, albeit in a small sample (n=13, 3 males, 10 females) that was referred to a clinic:

> The median age at the first incident was 19.5 months (range, 4-36 months); the median masturbation frequency, 4 times/day; and the median duration of each event, 3.9 min. The subjects masturbated in both prone (n=10) and supine positions (n=3); two subjects used the knee-chest position. All subjects showed facial flushing; 6, friction between the thighs; 5, sweating; 9, sleeping after the event; and 12, disturbance on interruption. EEG was abnormal in one of eight subjects tested, and neuroimages were normal in all of nine subjects examined. The case and control groups had comparable levels of all sex hormones, except estradiol, which showed significantly lower levels in the case group (P=.02).
>
> CONCLUSION:
> Masturbation in children seems to be associated with reduced estradiol levels, but not with other sex hormones. Further studies are needed to confirm our findings.

So, there was nothing too obviously wrong with these children otherwise...

The sample is from a clinic in Jordan but I didn't sense any obvious cultural bias, except for the higher presumed referral rate... and lack of follow-up:

> Since Jordan is a sexually conservative country with no formal sex education, childhood masturbation may create more parental concern than in Western societies, and the referral rate may differ. Ten (77%) of our children did not attend any follow-up visits after their parents were informed about the diagnosis of childhood masturbation, possibly due to the concern of stigmatization.

By the way, there is a term for this masturbation-like behavior in children (as mentioned in the paper) namely [gratification disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratification_disorder). Alas the Wikipedia article cites only a handful of even older articles, to say that not much research was done.

Some similar studies conducted [in the UK](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1719833/pdf/v089p00225.pdf) and [in Turkey](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10834518/) actually had somewhat larger samples, but otherwise there's not a lot to say about this. The UK study had a broader age range... and there's the odd bit about the car seat:

> Thirty one patients were diagnosed (11 males and 20 females). [...] The median age at first symptoms was 10.5 months (range 3 months to 5 years 5 months). The median age at diagnosis was 24.5 months (range 5 months to 8 years). [...] Events occurred in any situation in 10 children, and in a car seat in 11.

The discussion section also notes something about stigma:

> Masturbation in children is commonly recognised to be a
> variant of normal behaviour. Once the diagnosis is made and
> there are no suspicions of child sexual abuse requiring
> further investigation and management, reassurance seems to
> be the most effective management. Parents prefer the term
> gratification (or even benign idiopathic infantile dyskinesia)
> to infantile masturbation as there is less social stigma
> attached to these terms.

---

Classification-wise, one 2008 [review](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00431-008-0766-2) says that

> CM is defined as self-stimulation of the genitalia in a
> prepubescent child. It is not included in the DSM-IV,
> the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders
> (4th edition) of the American Psychiatric Association,
> which means that it is not classified as a (specific)
> psychiatric disorder. The WHO places (excessive) CM
> under the title “Other specified behavioural and emotional
> disorders with onset usually occurring in childhood and
> adolescence” (F98.8) in the ICD-10, the International
> Statistical Classification System of Diseases and Related
> Health Problems.

And to help answer your title question, this review actually does cite (and even include a table from) a study on prevalence, although this was assessed indirectly (parental reporting):

> In a study of Friedrich, the frequencies of a lot of
> different sexual behaviours in 1,114 2- to 12-year-old
> children were rated by their mothers (by means of the
> CSBI and the CBCL). Friedrich excluded children with a
> history or suspicion of sexual abuse in order to compose a
> normative sample. His results were consistent with earlier
> research and showed that a broad spectrum of sexual
> behaviours appears in children with varying frequencies.
> Self-stimulation is one of the most frequently seen sexual
> behaviours (Table 1).

[image]

That [study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9521975/) actually used a combined sample from Los Angeles and Minnesota, with the stated reason for doing so to average over possible cultural bias of the respondents.

There's yet another [2009 review](https://macpeds.com/documents/TheEvaluationofSexualBehaviorsinChildren.pdf) which is open-access, but on the broader topic sexual-like behaviors in childhood including such interactions with other children, exhibitionism etc. This review notes that "more than 50% of children will engage in some type of sexual behavior before their 13th birthday" but this is across the aforementioned broader range of behaviors. For childhood masturbation proper, they don't cite any other study besides Friedrich's already discussed above. But (I guess mainly from that) they summarize in a table of "Examples of Sexual Behaviors in Children 2 to 6 Years of Age" that "Normal, Common Behaviors" include "Touching/masturbating genitals
in public/private".

Actually Friedrich is a co-author to another [study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10506230/) that (using a translated questionnaire) had roughly similar findings in a Dutch sample, but a bit lower e.g. only 9.2% for "masturbates with hand" in the 2-5 y.o. I've cropped the most relevant part of their questionnaire report:

[image]

They also note some parental correlates of higher reporting, which not surprisingly include a more liberal attitude towards nudity, homosexuality etc.
A more [recent study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0145213419303539) mentions that results turned out not to be so easily generalizable because what parents report seems to vary across cultures...

> Comparison of the available research based on US, European, and Asian samples, reveals that European parents score highest on the CSBI total (de Graaf & Rademakers, 2007), whereas Asian children hardly show any sexual behavior according to the CSBI total score ([Jin, Chung, Jeong, & Lee, 2013](https://www.psychiatryinvestigation.org/journal/view.php?doi=10.4306/pi.2013.10.4.336)).

One good news (perhaps) is that within the same culture, mothers and fathers make consistent reports on their children. The latter paper does note, culture-wise:

> we must take into consideration the conservative Korean culture based on Confucian strictures including sexual taboos even among the adults, which likely affected the parents' ability to observe and report their children's sexual behavior.

Comment: For a more up-to-date review to the 2008 review linked, there is [Wilkinson & John (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pedhc.2018.05.001). It is also not in the latest DSM and *"The topic of hypersexuality was proposed but rejected for inclusion in the fifth edition by the American Psychiatric Association because it is not considered an unhealthy behavior"*.

Comment: @ChrisRogers: thanks, I don't mind at all if you contribute your own answer with the newer positions/research, as I'm not that up to speed with this topic (as you might guess from the incremental way in which I've expanded my answer.)